# DjnagoBecause its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, path, static

Someone could help, trying for weeks to figure out how to find the normal path. But it doesn't work.

**Script:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

#HTML Script

{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'CSS/Base.css' %}">

#Url.py Script

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('Website.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**Error code:**

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://46.251.28.105:8000/static/CSS/Base.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

**Path:**
`C:\Users\NexaHn\Desktop\Weboldal\AnimeEx\static`

Image:
[It loads in the wrong way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXIdn.png)

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG = False`, did you add the `STATIC_URL` url patterns to the `urls.py`?

Comment: Yes I added it to urls.py.